# In AngularJS, how to temporarily remove a model property when a form field is disabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please have a look at this example:

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/zxWLeZ

I'm developing a similar form where I have some data that the user can opt out of entering by clicking a checkbox. I'm using `ng-disabled` to disable the pertinent field ("Age" in my example) when the checkbox is checked.

That works fine if they click the checkbox before they enter data into the field. However, if they enter data into the field, *then* click the checkbox to disable it, the data both stays in the model and the view; it's just now locked from changes.

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Even if the user has entered data into the field that they then disable, remove that data from the model. In the example, if the checkbox is checked and "Name" and "Age" are both filled out, I'd want my user object to still only be:

  ```
  { "name": "John" }
  ```

  whereas it's currently:

  ```
  { "name": "John", "age": 35 }
  ```

Also, ideally:

- Remove the data from the view as well (i.e., empty out the "Age" field).
- Make that data removal (both from the model and view) reversible. If a user enters their age as `35`, then they check the checkbox to disable it, they'll see the "Age" field empty (and the `user` model will also lose the `age` property). Then, if they uncheck the checkbox, the value `35` will return to both the "Age" field and the model. In other words, don't lose their work if they change their mind.
- Do this at scale (e.g., with a reusable directive, relatively simple expression, or other DRY approach), since my form is complex with numerous instances of this behavior, and there will be other similar forms to come.

My first thought was that I need to either (basically the same thing, I think?):

- conditionally set `ng-model` for the "Age" field depending on the checked state of the checkbox
- unbind the "Age" field when the checkbox is checked, and re-bind it when unchecked

But, how do I do that? Or is there a simpler approach?

I've played around for a while, but can't find a combination of directives or other approach to do this, and it's proven hard to search for. I'm diving into the docs now, but could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to remove some of the model properties ? Or is it that the requirement is to just not show the content for the disabled fields ?

Comment: Sure! This form will ultimately be submitted to a server, and we only want to submit data from form controls that aren't disabled (otherwise we could collect "trash" data from controls that the user begins to fill out, but then disables). We've made the decision that backend will be relatively dumb, and just store what's handed to it. Since Angular doesn't automatically remove properties from the model when the form control is disabled (at least via `ng-model`), I need to build that functionality.

Comment: So, the easiest path - which I'm fine with, at least for now - would be to just delete the property from the scope that's bound to the control via `ng-model`, if/when that form control is disabled. Ideally, though, I'd prevent the user from losing work by storing the control's existing data somewhere, so if they then change their mind and decide to reenable the control, it still has the value they'd set previously. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a directive for both the checkbox and textbox.

Based on your code pen, the age control directive below will do it:

```
angular
  .module('example', [])
  .controller('exampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
  }).directive('ageControl',
    function() {
        return {
            template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="hideAge" ng-click="setAge()" />Hide Age<br />Age: <input type="text" ng-model="age" ng-disabled="hideAge" />',
            scope: {
              age: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
              var lastAge = null

              scope.setAge = function() {
                if (scope.hideAge) {
                lastAge = scope.age;
                scope.age = undefined;
              }  else {
                if (lastAge) {
                    scope.age = lastAge;
                }
              }
           }
        }
      }
   });
```

Working codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYxMQL

You would just need to parameterize the labels to make it work for any value.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of a directive that allows a checkbox to disable one or more form controls, removing the pertinent values from the model:

http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/XJExaO?editors=101

Comment: Thanks Ben! This does work, but I have some concerns about extensibility. Some of the form sections where I'll use this have one input, but others have 10 or more. Would I really need to create a separate directive for each section with essentially the same link function? Maybe I don't follow what you mean by parameterize the labels - can you give an example?

Comment: This gets me to thinking, though - maybe create an attribute directive that I could apply to any input, and if it the input becomes disabled, temporarily remove its own value from $scope until reenabled? I'll give that a shot.

Comment: You wouldn't need to create more than one directive. I made a specific one to match your example, but it's easy to genericize. Took me about 2 minutes to update my example Plunker to do any value.

Comment: Can you share that example? Sorry, I haven't been using Angular for long, so an explicit example is very helpful. I've written about 2 custom directives so far, and each took a lot longer than 2 minutes. ;-) I generally see what you mean, but, for example: since the directive specifies a template, it's bound to the HTML and thus I don't see how to reuse it with different HTML (e.g., a single checkbox that disables 10 form fields).

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful - but please note the end of my last comment - this won't always be a one-for-one relationship between checkbox and input. In many cases, a single checkbox will disable a full form section composed of many inputs. Sorry if I hadn't made that clear previously.

Comment: No, that wasn't clear. This shows an attribute directive that will do it for any number of inputs, you just have to supply the checkbox for each section: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYVqxr

Comment: Sorry about that - I can see how I didn't get that across. Your latest example is exactly what I was aiming for, though. I noticed that the fields wouldn't reenable if you disabled them before entering anything, so I made an adjustment to use `ng-disabled` instead: http://codepen.io/troywarr/pen/XJExaO?editors=101. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

An ideal approach would be to make use of `angular.copy()` function. When you Check hide, Store the array or object in a $scope variable. When you uncheck, restore again. See this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEdJWB).